# Eclipse not working with Mac OS X exposé

Tags: eclipse, apple-expose

I am running last Eclipse Helios for C++ under latest Mac OS X Leopard. When switching between programs using MAc OS X's exposé, I have always to repeat the process twice, until I get the eclipse window. This is very unconfortable. Anybody found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=306941#c4

fixed in 3.7rc1, yeay!

Comment: Hi, I followd the download link, but refers to Equinox. I need to work with eclipse CDT, how can I translate the equinox to the CDT?

Comment: Well I imagine you could just install CDT related stuff via the update manager in equinox until they release it and have all the different prebundled packages

Comment: hi! new release of eclipse CDT (8.0) was released two days ago, do you know if the same errors persist???